# Append or Prepend Elements to the Body of a Page

Tags: jquery, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to inject a div to the body of a page from `content_script`. I tried it with following code:

**Approach 1:**

```
$('body').prepend('<div  id="topbar"></div >');
```

**Approach 2:**

```
$('html:not(:has(parent)) > body:first').prepend('<div  id="topbar"></div >');
// Several other similar approaches.
```

but the problem here is that, it injects this div to all the body's it(jquery selector) found. **i.e.** if a page contains an `iframe` then, this div will be injected to it also, since the ifrmae contains a body.

Actually, the `Approach 2` shown above works well in normal script/web files, but not in chrome's `content_script`. Please help me to resolve this.

**content_script:**

```
var jqueryScript = "Javascript/References/jquery-1.7.min.js";
var topBarPage = "TopBar.html";

// Handle the requests.
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request.method == "dockPopup"){
        injectPopupToPage();
        sendResponse({});
    }
    else if(request.method == "undockPopup"){
        removePopupFromPage();
        sendResponse({});
    }
    else{
        sendResponse({});
    }
});

// Add the popup/topbar to page
function injectPopupToPage(){

    // Create script element
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = chrome.extension.getURL(jqueryScript);

    // Append jquery to page header.
    $('head').append(script);

    // Move the page down. >>>>>>>>>>>> Tried with various ways with no luck!!!!
    $('body').css('marginTop','39px');
    $('body').css('padding-top','64px');

    // Append the top bar to page.
    $('body').prepend('<div  id="topbar"></div >');
    $('#topbar').load(chrome.extension.getURL(topBarPage));

    $('#topbar').css({
        'background-color': '#FBC619',
        'position':'fixed',
        'left':'0',
        'top':'0',
        'width':'100%',
        'z-index':'9999'
    });
}

// Remove the Popup/Topbar from page.
function removePopupFromPage(){
    $('#topbar').remove();
    $('body').removeAttr('style');
}
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
 "name": "Inject",
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "version": "0.0.0",
 "description": "Inject.",
 "browser_action": {
   "default_popup": "Popup.html"
 },
 "permissions": [
   "tabs",
   "chrome://favicon/",
   "http://*/*", 
   "https://*/*"
 ],
 "content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["http://*/*"],
    "js": ["Javascript/References/jquery-1.7.min.js","Javascript/content_script.js"],
    "run_at": "document_start",
    "all_frames": true
  }
 ],
  "web_accessible_resources": ["TopBar.html","Javascript/TopBar.js","Javascript/References/jquery-1.7.min.js"]
}
```

Comment: Please put the code of your extension in plaintext on Stack Overflow. If the size is too big, try to reduce the code to a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). If that fails as well, try http://pastebin.com/ or http://pastie.org/

Comment: Is there a particular browser you experience this behavior with? I tried selecting `$('body')` on a page with an iframe in Chrome and I only got one body back, not two.

Comment: @RobW - Updated the question with code.

Comment: @ChrisPratt - I'm experiencing this issue only in chrome-extension. If I write similar selector in `chrome-console` or in any other normal web page it works fine.

Comment: @Knvn I suspect that you're injecting the code with `"all_frames": true`, which should be false if you only want to execute code in the top-level frame. Make sure that `manifest.json` is included in your question, because the contents of this file is significant.

Comment: @RobW - Correct catch! thanks....it fixed the issue. Please post it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by [Rob W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938089/rob-w) on the comment, I need to set `all_frames` false in `manifest.json` file.

Here is the modified **manifest.json** file:

```
{
 "name": "Inject",
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "version": "0.0.0",
 "description": "Inject.",
 "browser_action": {
   "default_popup": "Popup.html"
 },
 "permissions": [
   "tabs",
   "chrome://favicon/",
   "http://*/*", 
   "https://*/*"
 ],
 "content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["http://*/*"],
    "js": ["Javascript/References/jquery-1.7.min.js","Javascript/content_script.js"],
    "run_at": "document_start",
    "all_frames": false
  }
 ],
  "web_accessible_resources": ["TopBar.html","Javascript/TopBar.js","Javascript/References/jquery-1.7.min.js"]
}
```

Comment: +1-ed this answer, and -1-ed the other one, so that this answer shows up on top.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
$(document.body).prepend('<div  id="topbar"></div >');
```

Since you're directly referencing the main document (you would need to traverse down to get the the iframe's body), there's really no way it can select anything but main `<body>` element. In fact, you're not selecting anything; you're just wrapping the jQuery object machinery around the regular old JS object.

If you *still* have problems, I don't know what to tell you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body:first').prepend('<div  id="topbar"></div >');
$('body').first().prepend('<div  id="topbar"></div >');
$('body').eq(0).prepend('<div  id="topbar"></div >');
```

all gives you the first body element.

Comment: Tried all these...still same result!